# can't get css style's working on input type tel/number only

Tags: android, html, css, numbers, tel

I'm having some real problems getting input type=tel or input type=number to work on every mobile device. It looks fine on Samsgung s7, iphone 6, hell even an LG K500K. But won't work on my HTC M9 or a Samsung Note. I've checked versions of androids and it seems fine one is using 6.0.1 and the other is on 6.0. I've tried using both a class and also input[type=tel/number] and even just input on it's own :( i looked around online for hours and couldn't find one person who's experiencing this same incosistency. Does anybody have any advice

Comment: what problems do you experience concretely?

Comment: on the devices i mentioned "wont work" they see no styling on that input field

Comment: according to this page the support is very limited: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp only safari 8 has styling

Comment: it's working on most phones/and all pc's. so i think maybe it's like a browser problem or android version problem or something?